# GeoJSON generator with OpenLayers support

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

Is there a service that allows me to draw on an OpenLayers map, and see the resulting GeoJSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like jsfiddle or jsbin and manipulate the map using javascript, eg http://jsbin.com/exabev/1/edit.

This will allow you to make live changes and see them on the map in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.  Are you looking for an existing service, or want to create one?  Or are you trying to set something up for your users to output GeoJSON?

OpenLayers natively supports GeoJSON and can write to it as well.  You should look at this example and see how they write out to different formats.  It won't be difficult at all to extend and add GeoJSOn to the dropdown.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

Comment: I'm looking for an existing service.

Comment: then why Openlayers if you're really just after GeoJSON output?

Comment: Any visualisation would be fine - as long as I can draw a polygon and be given the GeoJSON representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `QGIS`. You need to first download and install it, and then install the `Openlayers` plugin. Add a layer from OpenLayers and zoom to your area of interest (it can sometimes take a few seconds to load and update the layer). Then, you can create a new vector layer, click on the editor icon, and draw over the basemap. You can then save your layer as a GeoJson (right click on layer, and choose GeoJson).